# How to upload 10GB+ files in IIS 10 and ASP.NET WebAPI 4.7.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, windows-server-2016

My goal is to upload large files, 10GB+ using IIS 10 / Windows Server 2016 and WebAPI 4.7.2.

Now, I realize this question has been asked repeatedly over the last 20 years.  However, after spending significant time reviewing these existing questions I have found that:

- No one talks about uploading > 4 GB files; this is too small
- A lot of solutions involve workarounds like using "Chunked" upload - I would like to use regular HTTP

Currently my web.config looks like this:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1002400" enableVersionHeader="false" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
```

And:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1547483648" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

It is my understanding that setting these limits > 2GB and > 4GB will not work due to the size of these data types.

So - the question is - how do we actually upload large files using ASP.NET WebAPI and the latest version of IIS?  It's 2020, surely Microsoft has a way for us to do this?

If it is NOT possible, we should start a petition for Microsoft to fix this because these kinds of limits should not exist.

Comment: Microsoft won't fill every gaps and that's why third parties are out there, https://www.telerik.com/blogs/upload-large-files-asp-net-radasyncupload and the strategy is rather simple, "dividing the large files into smaller chunks and uploading them subsequently."

Comment: @LexLi But is your answer that it is NOT possible out of the box?

Comment: You might get some ideas from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1#upload-large-files-with-streaming But Microsoft only used ASP.NET Core as an example. If you want the same for .NET Framework 4.x, more custom code is needed.